# How can I log out a user, with PHP or javascript, from my site when they close the browser tab?

Tags: php, javascript, logout

I've noticed that my users stay logged in even if they close the browser tab.

How can I automatically log them out if they close the browser tab?

Comment: `logged in` to what? What are looking at that says they are still logged in; a database (MySQL)? At best this question is really ambiguous at worst not a question at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [session cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), the cookie will be deleted when broswer session exists.

Answer (score -2):

With PHP you can store it's information in sessions (`$_SESSION`) , sessions are used to pass information between your PHP scripts as long as the session it's still available, and by default sessions are closed when the user close the web page so you can do something like this:

```
<?php
// you must first start your session on every page that would need it
session_start();

//login.php
login($usr,$password);

function login($usr,$password){
    $_SESSION['usr'] = $usr;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
}

// and when you decide to logout
function logout(){
    session_destroy();
}
```

And in every other part you may need to access that information you'd get it from `$_SESSION['usr']`.
Check more information about sessions in here: [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Comment: This answer is incomplete and misleading. You never start your session, nor do you mention that the session can be destroyed when the user decides to "log out" without closing the browser.

Comment: Adding it to my code, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Just FYI, that's not my -1 up there. I don't think this was so bad it needed a down-vote. It just doesn't deserve a +1.

Comment: Yeah i just hate that someone downvotes anything without saying why, it's kind of pointless IMO.